# scripts.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED running ng serve

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular. I was able to run my angular application locally until I pushed it to heroku. This error shows up on my local machine. On heroku, it has another error `Unexpected token <` not sure if it's related. 
So I do not know where to go to debug this error `scripts.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED` and `scripts.bundle.js 404 (Not Found)`. This error shows up at the root of the app. Any guidance or some kind of direction would be really appreciated!

package.json

```
{
  "name": "user-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",    
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "express": "4.16.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2": "^1.0.7",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.7.4",
    "nouislider": "^10.1.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "typescript": "2.6.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.6.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.16",
    "@types/node": "~8.0.47",
    "codelyzer": "~4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.8.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.5",
    "npm": "5.5.1"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<head>
<base href="/">
</head>
<body class="full-screen">
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Comment: Not sure if this will fix your problem, but why is it like this `"start": "ng server.js",` instead of `"start": "ng serve",`  in `package.json`?

Comment: @amal yeah I still get that problem. That was changed to `ng server.js` run in heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Check tag `<base href="/">` in your index.html page. If `<base href="/YOUR_APP_NAME/">` then it will gives same error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error updating angular 4 to 5 and cli 1.4.7 to 1.5

I fixed it running:
`npm cache verify`

I hope that will solve your problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the polyfills related issues comes due to browser compatibility, so you can try upgrading the browser to latest version.